# Coroutine: How to tell if a windows fiber has finished execution?

Tags: c, windows, coroutine, fiber

I have the following function that I use as an entry point for a windows fiber.

```
void foo(void*) {
    for(int i =0; i < 10; ++i) { doStuff(); }
}
```

Now I call `SwitchToFiber` in my main in a for loop; something like the following.

```
int main() {
    ... create the fiber and stuff

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
        SwitchToFiber(foo_fiber_ptr);
        // how do I tell if foo has already finished execution?
        // (without passing in a state variable to communicate.)
        if (someCondition) { break; }
    }

    ... do stuff
}
```

So my question is:
how do I tell if foo has already finished execution?(without passing in a state variable or declaring a global state variable to communicate.)

Answer (score 0):

Declare a global variable. After executing the `foo` function, change the state of the global variable in `foo`.

In `main` check for the state change. If the state of the global variable is changed, means `foo` has already been executed.

Comment: thanks, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this not through checking a user-defined state variable?

Answer (score 0):

> how do I tell if foo has already finished execution?

You tell that seeing your whole program's termination - see [Fibers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682661(v=vs.85).aspx):

> *If your fiber function returns, the thread running the fiber exits.*